# How to bind an image to the image-section which is the response from backend in vue.js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

In front end i developed one page which displays all the books the data is coming from the backend ,The response which is coming from backend includes file(image), how to bind that image into the image-section ,in my case i am unable to bind that image to the template section , please help me to get that image and display that image ,i am getting image path which coming from database please help me to convert that path to image in my page..

`DisplayNotes.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <!--{{book.file}}-->
<img url={{book.file}} />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-section">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by {{book.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. {{book.price}}<label>(2000)</label>
            <button type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();">close</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            books:[{
                id:1,
                file:'i want to display image',
                name:'Dont Make me think',
                author:'sai',
                price:'1500'
            },]
        }
    },
    methods:{
        handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {
                this.books.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

[image: How i am getting but i want to display image in place of path]

[image: like this image is storing inside my database]

`axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'
// process.env.VUE_APP_AXIOS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
axios.defaults.baseURL=process.env.VUE_APP_AXIOS_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer'+ localStorage.getItem('token');
export default class AxiosService{
getData(url,data){
        return axios.get(url,data).then(response =>{
            return response;
        })
    }
}
```

`User.js`

```
import AxiosService from '../service/axios';
const axios=new AxiosService()

export default{
 userDisplayBooks(data){
        return axios.getData("/getBooks",data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's format of you image file? if it's a http link , try use `src` not `url` in img tag :

```
<img :src="book.file" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img v-bind:src="book.file" />
```

binding image link directly form data

Comment: @rajmohan, but image is not displayed in my UI page

Comment: @Sravani   the image file in                                                                                   
books:[{
                id:1,
                file:'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-n6j1D1QT3bY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rcAedQvzW4rxD8g7pzB7y4c3baBeA/mo/photo.jpg',
                name:'Dont Make me think',
                author:'sai',
                price:'1500'
            },]